# Android Studio App Inspection don't start : Could not launch inspector *.inspection: Failed during instantiating inspector with id *.inspection

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, okhttp, android-workmanager

I got a big problem...

The App Inspection of Android Studio don't start even after clearing caches, restart/delete AVD.

Steps done:

1. Clear Caches
2. Update All
3. Delete/Recreate AVD
4. Read All The Logs

When using it **on other project it works** but **on this one it don't**.

The only differences between other project and this one are :

Using OkHttp and Workmanager :

```
//okhttp
// define a BOM and its version
implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:5.0.0-alpha.11"))

// define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
```

Even the logs don't show any differences.
I have digged on internet and found nothing.
Please I need expert helps.

Answer (score 5):

**FOUND THE ANSWER !!!**

I was targeting last SDK 34...

Retargeting all to SDK 33 solved the problems...

Comment: This is the only solution?

Comment: Clear `.idea` and `.gradle` folder in AndroidStudio path, retarget SDK. Then upper-left File:Invalidate Caches:Everything, then rebuild Project, now it should work!

Comment: To clarify my above comment : Clear `.idea` and `.gradle` folders in **AndroidStudio project path**. Then upper-left File:Invalidate Caches:Everything, then rebuild Project, now it should work! Also you shouldn't have any more bugs with SDK 34 as it is fully rolling out now.

Comment: Followed the above steps, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have been a problem in Android Studio with API Level 34. Has been fixed now.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297978282